# .net framework 4.7.2 and Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary v5 version incompatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, enterprise-library

I have my projects currently targeting .Net Framework 4.5.2 and using Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary.Data 5.0.505.0. If I change my projects target to .Net Framework to 4.7.2 I receive the error

> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.505.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

The Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data is referenced by the project and of the same version listed in the error, and if I change the target framework back to 4.5.2 I do not have this issue. Is there a compatibility issue between .net 4.5.2 and EnterpriseLibrary v5?

Comment: Hello, I checked many official documents and found no related issues about the incompatibility between .net framework 4.7.2 and Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary v5. Did you introduce Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary v5 directly or introduce a project with Microsoft EnterpriseLibrary v5?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I added the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibary .dlls as references for the project using it. (Right click project references > Add Reference)

Comment: Also these references have been in place for some time. As I mentioned, if I right click my project, choose properties, then application, and change the target framework to .NET 4.5.2, there is no file exception, and it is only after changing the target to .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Hello, this is not the case under my test, can you provide a minimal reproducible example. If you go to the [Visual Studio Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) feedback, you may be able to get more help but still need a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by copying the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data file to my projects executable folder  which in my case was /bin/Debug/ .

Despite my reference having 'Copy Local' set to true the file was not copied. It's still unclear to me why the issue did not occur when changing the target framework to .Net 4.5.2.